# ANY possible way to run the clang compiler from a Sandboxed app?

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, clang, sandbox

OK, the question is fairly straightforward.

I have a sandboxed OSX app.

I want the user to be able to compile some C code (whatever he inputs).

But whenever I'm attempting a call to:

```
/usr/bin/env clang /the/path/to/the/source.c
```

I'm getting the following error in the logs:

```
xcrun: error: cannot be used within an App Sandbox.
```

Is there **any** way to circumvent this?

---

P.S. I've successfully done pretty much the same thing with Ruby, Python and PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to keep your app sandboxed you could try to add a Temporary exception key to your entitlements file:

com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-only

More information on that [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html)

Another way to achieve it would be the more troublesome way of creating an helper app ([XPC-service](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html)) which is not sandboxed. There are also some details about XPC-services [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html).