# MacOS xcrun error preventing from invoking a shell script

Tags: xcode, shell, macos-catalina

I want to write a simple app that puts the result of the command

```
/usr/bin/strings myfile
```

into a label in the normal MacOS interface. I am receiving this error

> xcrun: error: cannot be used within an App Sandbox.

I tried to use the info here:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/73554

and here:

[ANY possible way to run the clang compiler from a Sandboxed app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082365/any-possible-way-to-run-the-clang-compiler-from-a-sandboxed-app)

The actual piece of code invoking the instruction is:

```
    let path = "/usr/bin/strings"
    let arguments = ["/path/to/my/file"]

    let task = Process()
    task.arguments = arguments
    task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let outputPipe = Pipe()
    let errorPipe = Pipe()

    task.standardOutput = outputPipe
    task.standardError = errorPipe

    do {
        try task.run()
        let outputData = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let errorData = errorPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(decoding: outputData, as: UTF8.self)
        let error = String(decoding: errorData, as: UTF8.self)
        testo.stringValue="OUTPUT: \(output)\nERROR: \(error)"
    } catch {
        lbl.stringValue="Error somewhere"
    }
```

Anyone does know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the command (/usr/bin/strings) but the access to the filesystem. In fact, replacing the first two lines with:

`let path = "/sbin/ping"
 let arguments = ["-c", "1", "www.google.com"]`

for instance, and allowing for outbound connections, would work fine. Hence, it is important that the application is allowed to access the path of the file to be processed, by means of the Sandbox.